# What Textmate theme do you use and why?

Tags: ide, editor, themes, textmate

What Textmate theme do you use and why? Just curious as to the best textmate themes out there and which ones you guys prefer?

Thankyou in advance ;-)

Comment: Should be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) you can ask this question in.